# Writing to array of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I need to write the pointer address of a struct (struct is called "Post") that has reposted another Post. There's a fixed return type called `result` with the following declaration:

```
struct result {
   void** elements;
   size_t n_elements;
};
```

For the Post struct, it has the following declaration:

```
struct post {
   uint64_t pst_id;
   uint64_t timestamp;
   size_t* reposted_idxs;
   size_t n_reposted;
};
```

Here's my code:

```
result* find_all_reposts(post* posts, size_t count, uint64_t post_id, query_helper* helper) {

result * ret_result = (result *) malloc(sizeof(result));
ret_result->elements[100];
ret_result->n_elements = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

    post * temp = &posts[i];

    size_t total_reposted = temp->n_reposted;

    if(total_reposted > 0){

        for(int q = 0; q < total_reposted; q++){

            int index_of_repost = temp->reposted_idxs[q];
            ret_result->elements[q] = &posts[index_of_repost];
            ret_result->n_elements++;
        }   
    }
}

return ret_result;
}
```

However I get a SEGV error for `ret_result->elements[q] = &posts[index_of_repost];`. I thought it could be originally that I hadn't initialised the elements field in the `ret_result` struct but I receive `warning: statement with no effect` for that:

```
warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]- ret_result->elements[100];
```

I'm thinking that the `void **` type for the `elements` field in `result` might be messing me around. From what I understand that's a pointer to a pointer which can obviously be an array and hence is basically a pointer to an array of posts?

I should clarify that `count` is the number of posts and that the returned-result is managed separately and hence any heap-allocated memory is freed in a separate process.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just what do you think `ret_result->elements[100];` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `ret_result->elements` to anything. The statement `ret_result->elements[100]` is a no-op, the only reason you're not segfaulting there too is because your compiler is cutting it out. If you want that field to be a pointer to an array of size 100 you must initialize it with malloc. I'm not sure why you're declaring it to be a `void **` double pointer here, but if it must be that way then something like this might work:

```
ret_result->elements = malloc(100 * sizeof(struct post *));
```

The call's arguments could also be `100 * sizeof(void *)`, but it might be a little what you intend to store there if you specify the struct to which the data will be pointing.